# Breaking out of loop in PHP and resetting the counters

Tags: php

There is some logic error in my code and I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Setting up things first, I have a .json file that I am reading which is in this layout:

[image]

So the polygon element is at every 1, 3, 5, .. and the school name is one prior to that.

Now I have another .csv file from where I am taking different lat and long values. Basically I have to see if that lat long from the csv file is inside any of these polygons as described in the json file.

Here is my part of the PHP code that takes in the json file and csv file. My logic is that, I take one lat and long value from the CSV and then want to go over each polygon in the json file.

If you follow the code below, I take in the values and when I meet the condition that it is outside a polygon, it just breaks out of the second while loop, takes another set of lat and longs.

```
$string = file_get_contents("Schools.json", 0, null, null);
    $json_a = json_decode($string, true);

    $start_row = 4;
    $rowID = 1;
    $polygonIndex = 1;
    $insideCheck = 0;
    $file = fopen("ActiveProperty.csv", "r");
    while (($row = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE){
        if($rowID >= $start_row){
            $points = array($row[52] . ' ' . $row[49]);
            $polygonIndex = 1;
            while ($polygonIndex < 454){
                $polygon = $json_a[$polygonIndex]['Polygons'];
                foreach($points as $key => $point) {
                    if ($pointLocation->pointInPolygon($point, $polygon) == "outside"){
                        echo "point " . ($key+1) . " ($point): " . $pointLocation->pointInPolygon($point, $polygon);
                        echo "<br>";
                        $polygonIndex = $polygonIndex + 2;
                        echo $polygonIndex;
                        $insideCheck = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        echo $json_a[$polygonIndex - 1];
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo "point " . ($key+1) . " ($point): " . $pointLocation->pointInPolygon($point, $polygon);
                        echo "<br>";
                        $insideCheck = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if ($insideCheck = 0) {
                    echo "out of foreach 0";
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    echo "out of foreach";
                    $insideCheck = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        $rowID++;
    }
```

Here is a sample output that I have:

[image]

Lat and longs in this image is from the csv file.

The expected output should be that with that lat and long, it should go over the polygons in the json and if its inside, return the first element which is the school. Here $polygonIndex just stays 3 which I am guessing is the issue.

If this is still unclear what I am trying to do, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem entirely.  But if you need to break out of the outter loop, you could try `break 2`;

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: So look at the `if ($pointLocation->pointInPolygon($point, $polygon) == "outside")` line. What I am trying to do here is that if this condition is met, meaning the point is not that given polygon, it should go to the next one. I increment my polygonIndex by 2 to go over the next one and then break the foreach loop after declaring a variable insideCheck = 0. Now for somereason "out of foreach" is being echoed which I dont know how it is meeting that condition.

Comment: `foreach($points as $key => $point) {` will do only 1 iteration, because `if (statement) { ... break; } else { ... break; }` In all cases you are breaking the loop

Comment: @Cid that is what I am trying to do. So `if ($pointLocation->pointInPolygon($point, $polygon) == "outside")` is met true, then it should exit foreach loop and go back to the `while ($polygonIndex < 454){` with the updated polygonIndex.

Comment: @Gauzdx you are breaking the loop in the `else` part too.

Comment: @Cid so you're saying that since foreach is run only 1 time, there is no need to use break?

Comment: @Cid does that break take me out of this `while ($polygonIndex < 454){` loop?

Comment: No, I'm wondering why you are iterating only once. By the way, what is common in the `if () { ... } else { ... }` could be placed outside of the condition

Comment: `if ($insideCheck = 0)` <-- you meant `==`